# Import local database to remote host Docker container

Tags: mysql, database, docker

I used my local mysql Docker container to dump a small and trivial test database. See:

```
docker exec -it [container] mysqldump -u root test > dump.sql
```

I'm trying to import `dump.sql` to a remote mysql Docker container with:

```
docker exec -i [container] mysql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xx.xxx -p password test < dump.sql
```

However it returns the help for mysql so I must have improper usage. What am I missing?

Comment: `-it` is not needed in when running mysqldump. The flag `-t` should only be used when running interactively. Using it non-interactively could lead to a different result (for instance adding CR "carriage return")

Answer (score 1):

Below command works for me.

Importing Database Dump into Docker Command:

```
podman exec -i [CONTAINER ID] sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" [DATABASE]' < restspring_mysql_db_dump.sql
```

**DETAILED STEPS:**

Pull MySQL Image Command:

```
podman pull mysql:8
```

Run Podman Command:

```
podman run -d --name mysql-8 -p 3316:3316 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:8
```

Export Database Command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p restspring > restspring_mysql_db_dump.sql
```

List Containers Command:

```
podman ps
                                                                                        
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                      COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                   NAMES
c6071ab6a192  docker.io/library/mysql:8  mysqld      45 minutes ago  Up 45 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:3316->3316/tcp  mysql-8
```

Importing Database Dump into Docker Command:

```
podman exec -i c6071ab6a192 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" mysql' < restspring_mysql_db_dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the shell command as part of my Docker command did the trick. Is shell the command necessary because the Docker command to import does not include -t ?

Comment: Hi @Astrodude11, not sure. I am still in learning phase