# Problem running mariadb dump in docker container

Tags: docker, mariadb

I got a MariaDB database dump from a colleague, and he asked me to run it in a docker container.
So i executed the following:

```
docker pull mariadb:10.4.26
```

then created the container

```
docker run --name test_smdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<some_password> -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:10.4.26
```

then connected to the container:

```
docker exec -it test_smdb mariadb --user root -p<some_password>
```

and created a database in it from the mariadb prompt:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE smdb_dev;
```

So far, so good. But when i tried to import the dump into it via this command:

```
docker exec -i test_smdb mariadb -uroot -p<some_password> --force < C:\smdb-dev.sql
```

i get a lot of lines like
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected.

So i am not sure what exactly is the issue?

1. Should i define a database, in which the dump should be imported? If yes - how exactly, because i look at different pages, like:
   https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb, especially this:

```
$ docker exec -i some-mariadb sh -c 'exec mariadb -uroot -p"$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD"' < /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

and i see no database mentioned here.

Or
2) The colleague has not created the dump in the correct way?

Comment: Hope the answer to this post is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72066070/import-local-database-to-remote-host-docker-container/72069437#72069437

Answer (score 1):

I do not use mariadb in a docker environment at my place, but I do use mariadb on a linux machine so it should be really similar.

You said you used this command :

> `docker exec -i test_smdb mariadb -uroot -p<some_password> --force < C:\smdb-dev.sql`

If we breakthrough it :

- `docker exec -i test_smdb` docker stuff where you ask docker to execute the following command on the `test_smdb` container (or close to it, I'm not a docker daily user).
- `mariadb -uroot -p<password> --force` here is the interesting part. You ask your shell to open mariadb and login as `root` with then given password with an extra flag `--force`. **But you never specify which database should be overridden**.

In my gist, again for mariadb outside docker but I really think it should be the same, I've the following command `mariadb -uusername -p<password> <DB_NAME> < /path/to/file.sql`

So I would try something like :
`docker exec -i test_smdb mariadb -uroot -p<some_password> smdb_dev --force < C:\smdb-dev.sql`

Answer (score 1):

Below command should work I believe

```
docker exec -i test_smdb sh -c "exec mariadb -uroot -pPASSWORD smdb_dev" < /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

Reference: [Import local database to remote host Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72066070/import-local-database-to-remote-host-docker-container/72069437#72069437)

Comment: Thanks, Vasanth, but when i tried to execute this, i got : mariadb: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: I tested this in Mac and it worked fine. Looks like you are using Windows. If so, can you try hard coding the password without quotes and check once? Thank you

Comment: Depend on if the `test_smdb` was started with the `$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD` set. Also the contents password is expanded by bash so if it contains quotes that could explain the error.

Comment: Thanks Vasanth, but i hardcoded the password and i faced the same issue

Comment: Got it, try replacing single-quotes with double-quotes, it should work. Got a chance to test in Windows environment and it worked for me. Thank you!